# Creating default object from empty value, when updating

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to update the questions on a survey but I'm getting this error and I'm nor sure why, This is the code where I'm trying to update

```
if ($request->question_id) {
    $ids = [];
    foreach ($request->question_id as $number => $item) {
        $questions = SurveySurveyQuestion::where('survey_id', $survey->id)
            ->where('survey_question_id', $item['id'])->first();
        if (empty($item['id'])) {
            $questions = new SurveySurveyQuestion();
            $questions->survey_id = $id;
            $questions->survey_question_id = $item['id'];
        }
        $questions->order = $number;
        $questions->save();
        $ids[] = $questions['id'];
    }

    if (count($ids) > 0) {
        SurveySurveyQuestion::whereNotIn('survey_question_id', $ids)
            ->where('survey_id', $survey->id)->delete();
    }
}
```

The error shows on line

> $questions->order = $number;

EDIT: Now it saves the new questions added but when I either try to reorder the questions or remove one I get this error

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `survey_survey_questions` set `order` = 0 where `id` is null)

Why is this happening?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: because the method `first()` can return `null` if it doesn't find anything and you're trying to assign an attribute on 'null'.

Comment: @MahabubulHasan it's in the question title

Comment: @N69S What should I use instead?

Comment: check if you have a question to update before trying to update it. and i dont know how your application is behaving/should behave in those cases. It's up to you.

Comment: @N69S the outer `if` statement does that

Comment: @Nancy try `if (empty($item['id']) || !$questions) {` instead of `if (empty($item['id'])) {`

Comment: @MahabubulHasan This helped, I'll edit my question to show what's happening now

Comment: @Nancy what is the value of `$id` in `$questions->survey_id = $id;`, BTW, seeing the partial code it is tough to assume what's happening in the code

Comment: @MahabubulHasan I did get it to work, with your suggestion ill post the answer

Comment: @Nancy what's in `$request->question_id` ? the name hints for an integer but you are looping on it as an array ? the fact that an id is coming from the request doesn't mean that the id is present in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution I arrived to

```
if ($request->question_id) {
    $ids = [];
    foreach ($request->question_id as $number => $item) {
        $questions = SurveySurveyQuestion::where('survey_id', $survey->id)
            ->where('survey_question_id', $item['id'])->first();
        if (empty($item['id']) || !$questions) {
            $questions = new SurveySurveyQuestion();
            $questions->survey_id = $id;
            $questions->survey_question_id = $item['id'];
            $questions->order = $number;
            $questions->save();
        } else {
            SurveySurveyQuestion::where('survey_id', $survey->id)
                ->where('survey_question_id', $item['id'])->update(['order' => $number]);
        }
        $ids[] = $item['id'];
    }
    if (count($ids) > 0) {
        SurveySurveyQuestion::whereNotIn('survey_question_id', $ids)
            ->where('survey_id', $survey->id)->delete();
    }
}
```